# Excel text box content to cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I know there is an option to link cell content to text box so once you type to cell something it will be displayed in text box. Is there something similar but vice versa? Once I type to text box it will be displayed in cell.

I came up with this issue after inserting background and adding black box shape with transparency of 50%. I want to input some kind of text box on top of it so user will be able to input data. If I use cells they are hiding behind my black shape.

I need to link "Jack Daniels" box to cell so when user inputs something else instead of "Jack Daniels" or "Microsoft" result would go to some cell.

[image]

Comment: Please add an example of what you are describing. Perhaps an image. Just hit edit below your question and paste the *snipping tool* image capture (besure to click the *snipping tool* copy icon after capturing the image so it can be pasted) or paste a copied selection from your spreadsheet. In the dialogue that appears, click *add image* and the site will store the selection as an image and add an inline link to the stored image in the post.

Comment: @TedD. I have added more details to my question.

Comment: I guess I have to use ActiveX text boxes for this matter...